# .NET/ISS Applications do not show jqwidget icons or any relative icons

Tags: .net, fonts, icons

The icons will not show up because of the url. Going through the minified files and hard coding the url is not productive, nor does it work with updates.

Occasionally even hardcoding the URLs does not seem to work.

How do I tell .NET to simply use a relative url? This seems like a simple enough consistency that even a .html file written in notepad can do... but oh no... not wonderful Microsoft deployed web apps.

I have googled till I'm blue in the face and I'm not creating complex classes just to handle a font or icon. Well, it won't do any good if the url is in a minified file.

Can someone point me in the direction to a good resource to solve this annoying problem once and for all?

Comment: It’s difficult to find any errors if you don’t show your code.

Comment: @ZippyV You surely know the different between a hardcoded url and relative url right? There is no code to show. "~/Content/Images/icon.png" and "/Images/icon.png"

Comment: And there are no "errors" zippy... Read the question.